# Implementing linspace from python to C# to get a vector

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm translating an existing Python script into C# to use in a Unity project. I have some previous code that implements arange (bands and dx are numbers):
**Python:** `x = np.arange(dx/2,1,dx)`

translates to --

**C#:** `static readonly Vector<double> x = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(bands, i => dx / 2 + i++ * dx);`

But I've changed what I want the value of x to be in the Python code. I've changed it in Python to:

**Python:** `x = np.linspace(-1+dx/2,1-dx/2,n)`

But I'm struggling to figure out how to implement this new function (linspace) in C#. Any help would be appreciated. I'm thinking it's something like:

```
static readonly Vector<double> x = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(bands, i => -1 + dx / 2 + i++ * 1 - dx / 2);
```

But I think I am just not understanding how the first conversion is working.

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose easier route by writing a method if I were you.

```cs
List<float> CreateRange(float start, float stop, float step)
{
    List<float> list = new List<float>();

    // Some edge case handle(step = 0, step = (-)Infinity, etc

    if (step > 0)
    {
        for (; start < stop; start += step)
        {
            list.Add(start);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(; start > stop; start += step)
        {
            list.Add(start);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Of course unless that you have specific reason to must use one line code.

Comment: These are currently static variables being called by another script so id prefer to have everything done in the initialization.

Comment: @dacharya64 If you make method static then you can call it in field initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. It's:

```
Vector<double>.Build.Dense(bands, i => -1 + (dx / 2) + i++ * dx);
```